Design pattern to manage two functions with the same signature, but different parameter names in C++
My program interfaces with a computer vision library that uses 2D points (row, col) and it also interfaces with... let's say the rest of the world, which uses points (x, y). These points contain the same data: row==y and col==x, the only difference is the order of initialization.
I know that ideally I should choose only one way of initializing the points, that using two is a gateway to hell, but as I'm stuck between these two conventions, and as C++ sometimes looks like a Christmas tree with magical features, I was wondering if there was an elegant solution to deduce based on the name of the arguments:

createPoint(row, col)? Y is first!
createPoint(x, y)?     X is first!


Give them distinct types so you can't ever confuse them.

Variable names aren't part of a type, so no -- you cannot overload based on parameter names...

@Passer By Yes, this is a possible solution, but let's say we have
Pix(double row, double col) and Point(double x, double y), it's not impossible (even if this reduces the chances) that someone might do Pix(x, y).
My question mainly concerned the possibility for c++ to know the names of parameters, or at least to have a way of taking them into account.

You could use tag dispatch and overlad based on a "creation tag": createPoint(rc_t{}, row, col) would use row and col style and createPoint(xy_t{}, x, y) would use x and y.  Here rc_t and xy_t are just empty classes used to give the overloads distinct types


I was wondering if there was an elegant solution to deduce <an overload> based on the name of the arguments

No there isn't. Names of formal arguments have no effect on anything. In particular, this is a legal code (which can't be broken by future changes to standard):
int foo(int a, int b); //declares int foo(int, int)
int foo(int c, int d); //declares int foo(int, int)
int foo(int x, int y){ //defines int foo(int, int)
  //...
}

In your situation a good solution would be to implement two distinct types:
struct CellCoord;

struct Point {
  int x, y;
  //has to be defined out of class, writing like this for brevity
  /* implicit */ Point(const CellCoord& c) : x(c.col), y(c.row) {}
};

struct CellCoord {
  int row, col;
  /* implicit */ CellCoord(const Point& p) : row(p.y), col(p.x) {}
};

With this you can write every class in terms of one struct and pass another with the constructor handling the conversion:
//in part of the program working with points
void foo(Point p);
//in part of the program working with cells
void bar(CellCoord c);

Point p1, p2;
//since there is no two-argument constructor, clients of the class
//have to fill it explicitly naming fields thus decreasing the chance of error
p1.x = 17;
p1.y = getMyY();
foo(p1); //normal call
p2 = getPoint(5);
bar(p2); //calls bar(CellCoord(p2))

If you need an even better type safety, you may introduce special types for different coordinates instead of a generic int:
struct strong_typedef_int {
  int val;
  /* a bunch of overloaded operators */
};

struct Abscissa : public strong_typedef_int {};
struct Ordinate : public strong_typedef_int {};

struct Point {
  Abscissa x;
  Ordinate y;
  // and so on
};

However, this will make any kind of rotation very cumbersome to write, this technique is better reserved for different kinds of IDs and the like.

It's a shame this doesn't support designated initializers like createPoint({ .row = 4, .col = 5 }); createPoint({ .x = 5, .y = 4 }); because it's not an aggregate, but that opens the door to Point{ y, x };  // Accidentally flipped

@Artyer: with operator conversion, instead of constructors, we have aggregate :) Demo.

@Jarod42 The problem is, in your example Point p({my_y, my_x}); becomes also legal and that's hard to avoid. You would need to somehow ban initializers while allowing designated initializers... which could work if there's also an unassignable dummy field with a default value... with a [[no_unique_address]]... not sure if I want to include something like this in the answer proper.

Thank for this comprehensive reply,
The creation of specific types achieves the desired result: a compilation error if wrong parameters are passed. Bjarne Stroustrup recommends strongly typing code in this way, but it is indeed a tedious development.

Parameters names are not part of the function signature so the compiler would trigger a redefinition error for this function.
What you can do instead:

Name your two functions with different names:

void createPointRC(double row, double col);
void createPointXY(double x, double y);


Create specific types for a point (one with row/col syntax and the other one with the x/y syntax):

struct PointRC
{
    double row, col;
};
struct PointXY
{
    double x, y;
};

void createPoint(const PointRC & point);
void createPoint(const PointXY & point);


Create two namespaces, each one having its own function (so that you can keep the same names and argument types):

namespace rc
{
    void createPoint(double row, double col);
}

namespace xy
{
    void createPoint(double x, double y);
}


Other options are possible...

You may chose whatever solution that better suits your needs

As explained in the previous answers, there's no technique for really exploiting parameter names.
Inspired by the solution suggested by @Abstraction, I use a single class whose constructor is private. Instead, 2 static methods specify the initialization strategy: Point::XY(x, y) or PointRC::(row, col),
however, there's no formal guarantee or warning that parameters won't be inverted, as I'd hoped.
struct Point {
  int x, y;
  
  static Point RC(int row, int col){
        return {col, row};
  }
  
  static Point XY(int x, int y){
        return {x, y};
  }
    
  private :
    Point(int xx, int yy):x(xx), y(yy){}
};

